# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "180.234.124.218" , user "bcudchiocfkzuf", database "de6l7io3liaupc", SSL off

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I am hosting a laravel project on heroku for the first time. I've installed laravel and postgres successfully on heroku and it's run on the server. But when I ran the `php artisan migrate` command for the remote database it throws an error, which is;

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "180.234.124.218", user "bcudchiocfkzuf", database "de6l7io3liaupc", SSL off
```

Then I added to the pg_hba.conf file `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` (add this line at the bottom of the file), but it still shows the error again.

Comment: Where are you running this command from? Your local machine or the heroku instance?

Comment: did you restart the pg server after making changes to pg_hba.conf?

Comment: yes.i goto run and type service.msc and stop the postgres service and then run it again

Comment: i use win8 and postgres 9.3 on my local machine and postgres 9.3.5 on remote server

Comment: **SSL off**. AFAIK, Heroku requires SSL for all connections that aren't from a Heroku dyno.

Comment: I ran `heroku run php artisan migrate` and I was able to get my migrations. Make sure the .env vars are in your heroku project as well.